# Binding a dropdown using MVC + Entity Framework without ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dropdown

I'm new to MVC and I've been searching for a good solution to this problem, but I feel like I'm missing something every time I come across a solution that kind of works.  When I go to create the view, I select the model created by the datacontext and it auto-populates the page for me.  If this is not best practice then I would be open to an explanation of how to do this differently.

Now on to the topic of this question: building a dropdown menu.  I have been using ViewBag because it works, but I gather that this is not best practice.

This is directly from my InventoryRecord class generated by Entities:

```
namespace Inventory.DataContext

public partial class InventoryRecord {

    public Nullable<int> TypeId { get; set; }

}
```

As mentioned above, my view is populated by what Entities has created for me with a few modifications:

```
@model Inventory.DataContext.InventoryRecord
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="TypeId">Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("TypeId", null, "Select...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then in the controller I have this:

```
private InventoryDataSource db = new InventoryDataSource();
ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.Types.OrderBy(x => x.TypeDesc), "Id", "TypeDesc", type);
```

This works, but I would like to know how to do this without using ViewBag.  I have several other dropdown menus on the page and I would like to get into the habit of using MVC the way it was intended.

Comment: [ViewModels](http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/). Everything you need for the View should be put into a view model. Passing in an Entity Model is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested alaways go with viewmodel and Here is the example code for you

```
public class RoleViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Role :")]
        public string RoleCode { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<RoleViewModel> GetRoles()
        {
            return new List<RoleViewModel>
                            {
                                new RoleViewModel() {Id = 1, RoleCode = "Role 1"},
                                new RoleViewModel() {Id = 2, RoleCode = "Role 2"},
                                new RoleViewModel() {Id = 3, RoleCode = "Role 3"}
                            };            
        }
    }
```

**In View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleCode, new SelectList(new MvcApplication1.Models.RoleViewModel().GetRoles(), "Id", "RoleCode"))
```

Note : Just change according to your requirement and it will surely work.

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Like Steve said, dont pass Entity Model. Always create view model class for your views.

Add view model class:

```
public class InventoryRecordModel
{
   [Required]
   public int TypeId;
   //some other properties
}
```

Change view to:

```
@model InventoryRecordModel
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="TypeId">Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("TypeId", null, "Select...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Keep controller as it is.